# How to improve the wifi performance of openwrt

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, openwrt

If my computer download through my `tplink` router, the speed is 10Mbps, if through `openwrt` router, it's 5Mbps.

Here is wifi information:

```
root@localhost:/etc/config# iwconfig wlan0
wlan0 IEEE 802.11bg ESSID:"AndroidAP"
Mode:Master Frequency:2.427 GHz Access Point: 00:8E:0E:02:99:4E
Bit Rate:54 Mb/s
RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off

Encryption key:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=-95 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

If no traffic, the system information is as follow:

> Mem: 689272K used, 299240K free, 0K shrd, 10228K buff, 308060K cached
>
> CPU: 4% usr 2% sys 0% nic 92% idle 0% io 0% irq 0% sirq

If traffic is 5Mbps, it's

> Mem: 692320K used, 296192K free, 0K shrd, 10268K buff, 308060K cached
>
> CPU: 3% usr 2% sys 0% nic 89% idle 0% io 0% irq 3% sirq

The CPU is nearly idle.

I haven't install `qos` package, there is no qos config in `/etc/config`

I don't know why the WiFi performance of `openwrt` is so bad.

Please help me to improve WiFi performance.